# Splitting team names with scores separated by space and commas

Tags: java, regex

I've multiple lines of game scores as input. The input is something like this.

```
Lions 1, FCAwesome 1
```

I'm currently Splitting the line based on either comma or space.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
String REGEX = ",?\\s+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset)){

      int count = 0;
      String line = null;
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        String[] arr = pattern.split(line);
      }
```

This works fine for the provided input. However if the team name is has more than one word, my code breaks.

```
Lions 1, FC Awesome 1
```

How do I modify my REGEX to handle this case. FC Awesome still needs to be one team name.

Comment: Will input always be `[Letters & possibly spaces] [digits]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try splitting on space which

- has comma before it (including that comma) - to separate *team score* pairs.
- has digit after it - to separate *team name* and *score*,

So try with `split(",\\s|\\s(?=\\d)")`

---

If there is possible that some parts of team name can start with digit, we can specify our condition more. We can require from `[space][digit]` to either have after it comma or to be placed at the end of text.

`split(",\\s|\\s(?=\\d+(?=,|$))")`

Answer (score 0):

try to split whole data by comma, then use `getTeam` method below

```
class Team {

    String name;
    int score;

    public Team(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + ", " + this.score;
    }

    public static Team getTeam(String data) {    
        String score = "";    
        int i = data.length() - 1;    
        for (; Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i)); i--) {    
                score += data.charAt(i);    
        }    
        String name = data.substring(0, i);    
        return new Team(name, Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(score).reverse().toString()));
    }
}
```

for example input is like this

`LION_@# 1234 OLD 5555       ,TEAM2345NAME   NAME 123NAME 4444`

first name is `LION_@# 1234 OLD` and it's score is `5555`
 
second name is `TEAM2345NAME   NAME 123NAME` and `4444` is it's score

***note: both contain numbers or special characters in their name and even space in score part.***

now all i need is creating an instance of Team class.
like below example:

```
    String all_data = "LION_@# 1234 OLD 5555     ,TEAM2345NAME   NAME 123NAME 4444";
    // spliting data by comma
    String parts[] = all_data.split(",");

    // calling getTeam method
    Team t1 = Team.getTeam(parts[0]);
    Team t2 = Team.getTeam(parts[1]);
```

then use it's fields, for example print them.

```
    System.out.println(t1.name);
    System.out.println(t2.score);
```